# Why won't Ubuntu recognize my login and password?

Tags: 12.04

I can't do anything because Ubuntu always asks for a login and password. I have auto-login selected and it still asks for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *System settings* -> *Brightness and lock*. Turn the lock off, and disable *Require my password when waking from suspend*.